# Can we get data for various activity user is doing like running, walking, swiming, Bicycling etc?

Tags: jawbone

Copied from the old forum:

In data I want to have

1. Steps
2. Duration
3. Distance
4. Calories Burnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Workouts endpoint](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/endpoints/workouts) to retrieve this information for many different kinds of user activities.

Refer to that documentation to see the list of available workout types, and all four of those pieces of data (and more) are available for each workout.